# Using a JS function defined in an included library, my success & error callbacks do not fire. Issue with my JS or theirs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

Relatively new to Javascript/Jquery!

tl;dr **When I call a function (defined in an external library that I include), my success AND failure callback functions simply do not fire.  Given my code below, is this an issue with my javascript or theirs?**

I am using an external [API](http://spatialstream.com/microsite/ParcelStream.html) along with it's Javascript library, which I include like so:

**app/views/layouts/application.html.haml :**

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application'

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://parcelstream.com/api/DmpApi.aspx?map=Bing&services=Utility&host=parcelstream.com/&v=4"></script>
```

My javascript, which is run on page load:

**app/assets/javascripts/mine.js :**

```
function GetByGeometry(point) {

        function successCallback(json) {
            console.log("success callback called");
            // real code here, cut for brevity
        }

        function errorCallback(error) {
            console.log("error callback called");
            // real code here, cut for brevity
        }

        var url =   "getByGeometry.aspx?returnGeoType=1&dataSource=SS.Base.Parcels/Parcels&Geo=" + point;
        console.log("this is my query URL: " + url);

        Dmp.Env.Connections["SS"].getJson(url, successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

I am getting no feedback whatsoever.  Neither successCallback nor errorCallback are ever fired off, and I am not getting an error either.  What am I missing?  Is this an error on my end, or is there something wrong with their .getJson() function?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any clue about the Dmp.Env.Connections["SS"] object, so I cannot tell if that is working or not.

First thing to do is to look into the Network tab (under Developer Tools in Chrome) and check if an Ajax call is fired. This is will tell a lot - if a response is received from the server, if your payload is correct etc. I would start there, and then check for the API definition of Dmp.Env.Connections["SS"] and see if my arguments are correct.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion to look at the Network tab in Chrome!  This helped me to discover that my authentication with the external library's API (not shown here) was failing, and so my call to Dmp.Env.Connections["SS"] was never registering.  Thanks again!